# Why arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc cannot compile even simple test file?

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-platform, ubuntu-17.04

I installed cross-compilation tools on my Ubuntu system using:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

And then i made simple .c file which compiles ok, but when gcc runs assembler stage, it is for unknown reason invokes 'as' command, instead of appropriate 'arm-linux-gnueabi-as' command and as result compilation fails with following errors:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v test.c

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-12ubuntu2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-armel-cross/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-armel-cross --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-armel-cross --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libgcj --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv5t --with-float=soft --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 20170406 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-march=armv5t' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabi test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=soft -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase test -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/cccUVSll.s
GNU C11 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) version 6.3.0 20170406 (arm-linux-gnueabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0 20170406, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/6/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C11 (Ubuntu/Linaro 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) version 6.3.0 20170406 (arm-linux-gnueabi)
    compiled by GNU C version 6.3.0 20170406, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.5, MPC version 1.0.3, isl version 0.15
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 50226affb1339dba25cfdfb2ad79e687
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-march=armv5t' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 as -v -march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 -o /tmp/cczGBXSH.o /tmp/cccUVSll.s
GNU assembler version 2.28 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.28
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv5t'
```

As you can see, it fails, because it invoking wrong command - **as**, which knows only about **x86_64-linux-gnu** target, and does not recognizing **armv5t** architecture option.

How to force gcc toolchain to use correct cross-platform assembler/linker to produce binary, instead of 'as' 'ld' etc?
Is there something in my environment, that causing such behavior?

P.S. On my college's machine, installing same toolchain works without problem, however he has Ubuntu 16.04, while mine are 17.04..
And GCC executing following command for assembler:

> /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/as
>   -v -march=armv5t -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 -o /tmp/ccXru9b3.o /tmp/ccUwNPuq.s

As you can see, it takes right assembler and all is ok.. but not on my system..

Comment: What if you install gcc-5 like your college: `sudo apt-get install gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi` (run with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-5 -v test.c`)?

Comment: Just tried. Same story: wrong 'as' command.

Comment: I downloaded binary package from https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/
and run gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
everything works PERFECT.

I guess there's something broken in linux distro package(s).
Or i installed too much/some conflicting stuff, that made a mess..